# The following Regex does not work for "45"

Tags: regex

I have this regex that does not work for "45" it works fine for -1.3434 1.43454 (+-)[0-9].[0-9]

Regex: 
"^(\-)?[0-9]*+\.[0-9]*$"

Comment: "45" doesn't have a dot in it.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
^(\-)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

Explaining the pattern left to right

- Start at beginning of line - ^
- 0-1 of "-" character - (-)?
- One or more digits [0-9]+
- 0-1 of the group: literal period followed by one or more digits (.[0-9]+)
- Match to end of line $

Comment: I think you need a star or a plus on your trailing numbers.

Comment: Right - it doesn't match more than one decimal digit.

Comment: Will work only for one digit after dot

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be something like this, to allow the optional decimal:

```
^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

At the beginning of the string (`^`), there's an optional dash (`-?`), followed by some digits (`\d+`). Then it can also have one occurrence of a decimal (`\.`) followed by some digits (`\d+`) - all together as `(\.\d+)?`. Then it's the end of the string (`$`).

Note: the dash doesn't need to be escaped because it's outside of a character class.

Answer (score 0):

In your Regex dot symbol (.) is reqired. Try this:

```
^(\-)?[0-9]+(\.?[0-9]{1,})?$
```

### Fixed

Comment: [please explain the pattern](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177757)

Comment: Regular expressions are cryptic enough when written cleanly - try to avoid unnecessary clutter. You kept the unnecessary escaping and grouping of the dash. Why use [0-9] for digits when there's a shortcut "\d"? There's no need for the question mark quantifier on the decimal itself since you have another one on the whole matched group. Why use {1,} instead of the universal shortcut "+"?